# How can I log in to Stack Exchange using curl?

Tags: curl, credentials

I would like to log in to a remote website from Terminal, which requires an username and password to log in.

So I first tried to log in to one of the Stack Exchange site. [According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2594908/2360798), you use `-u username:password` to add your credentials.

So I tried the following:

```
USERNAME="mine@gmail.com"
PASSWORD="myPassword"

URL="https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/"
curl $URL -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD
```

But the resultant website is not a page that the logged-in user sees but it is a page that non-verified user sees, which shows a *Sign-up* button.

I feel that it works only on the cases where you type in your credentials at the pop-ups shown when you try to access it.

So how can I log in in these cases from within Terminal?

Comment: the `-u USER:PASS` option to curl will use basic authentication, which isn't how most websites handle authentication.  See answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

unfortunately, the login protocol is much more complex than that, and is not a scheme built-in to curl. this is not a job for curl, but some scripting language (like PHP or Python), though libcurl would be of great help to manage the http protocol and cookies and the likes. and libxml2 would be of help to parse out the login CSRF key, which is hidden in the HTML. and they may require a referer header, and they may even be checking that the referer header is real, not faked (idk, but it wouldn't surprise me).

first, make a plain normal HTTP GET request to https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/login , and make sure to save the cookies and the html response. now extract the POST URL and input elements of the form with id `login-form`, this includes the CSRF token, username, and password, and bunch of others. then make an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoded POST request to https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/login , with the cookies received from the first GET request, and the POST data of all the `<input` elements you extracted, and remember to fill out the "email" and "password" inputs.

NOW you should get the logged-in html, and to continue to get the logged-in version of the page, make sure to apply the same cookie session id to the next http requests (its this cookie session id that makes the website remember you as the guy that logged in on that account~)

here's an example in PHP, using libcurl and libxml2 (using PHP's DOMDocument as a convenience wrapper around libxml2, and using hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php as a convenience wrapper around libcurl, taking care of cookies, referers, libcurl error handling (turns silent libcurl errors into exceptions, and more), at the end, it dumps the logged-in HTML, proving that it's logged in. (and the email/password provided, is a dummy account for testing, there's no problem in it being compromised, which obviously happens when i post the credentials here.):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl ( 'https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/login', true );
// getting a cookie session, CSRF token, and a referer:
$hc->exec ();
// hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () );
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $hc->getResponseBody () );
$inputs = array ();
$form = $domd->getElementById ( "login-form" );
$url = $form->getAttribute ( "action" );
if (! parse_url ( $url, PHP_URL_HOST )) {
    $url = 'https://' . rtrim ( parse_url ( $hc->getinfo ( CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL ), PHP_URL_HOST ), '/' ) . '/' . ltrim ( $url, '/' );
}
// hhb_var_dump ( $url, $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () ) & die ();

foreach ( $form->getElementsByTagName ( "input" ) as $input ) {
    if (false !== stripos ( $input->getAttribute ( "type" ), 'button' ) || false !== stripos ( $input->getAttribute ( "type" ), 'submit' )) {
        // not sure why, but buttones, even ones with names and values, are ignored by the browser when logging in,
        // guess its safest to follow suite.
        continue;
    }
    // var_dump ( $input->getAttribute ( "type" ) );
    $inputs [$input->getAttribute ( "name" )] = $input->getAttribute ( "value" );
}
assert ( ! empty ( $inputs ['fkey'] ), 'failed to extract the csrf token!' );
$inputs ['email'] = 'vs5jkqyx4hw3seqr@my10minutemail.com';
$inputs ['password'] = 'TestingAccount123';
$hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( $inputs ),
        CURLOPT_URL => $url 
) );
$hc->exec ();

hhb_var_dump ( $inputs, $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () );
```

interesting note, by default, libcurl uses `multipart/form-data`-encoding on POST requests, but this site (and most sites, really), uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoding on POST requests. here i used PHP's http_build_query() to encode the POST data in in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-format

Comment: He never mentioned PHP in curl. he want to do it in terminal.

Comment: @SagarV i told him what he needs to do. but i didn't write the implementation for him. if you want to parse HTML from bash, go right ahead, implement it for him, but i sure don't want to parse HTML from the terminal.

Comment: _how can I log in in these cases from within Terminal_ this is his question. I think you missed it

Comment: @SagarV no i didn't. this piece of php code is perfectly executable from the terminal by installing php-cli and running `php script.php`

Answer (score 8):

You can do it via browser's tool. You need to copy cookies with all headers via Chrome browser > View > Javascript Console > Network > (right click)> Copy option menu > click select "Copy as cURL" :

[image]

Normally we curl in this way :

```
curl -c cookie.txt -d "LoginName=username" -d "password=changepassword" https://examplesite/a
curl -b cookie.txt https://examplesite/b
```

Copy via right click will be very big (of course I changed things to prevent myself getting hacked) :

```
curl 'https://meta.stackoverflow.com/' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'authority: meta.stackoverflow.com' -H 'cookie: prov=xxxxxxxxxxx; __qca=P0-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx; acct=t=xxxxxxxxxxxx; _ga=GA1.2.xxxxxxxx; _gid=GA1.2.xxxxxxx; _ga=GA1.3.xxxxxxx; _gid=xxxxxxxxx9' -H 'referer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/' --compressed
```

Comment: that technically does not log in with curl, but rather fetches the front page, using an existing already-logged-in cookie session from the browser. also it will stop working once that cookie session expires, OR he logs out in his browser, whichever comes first.

Comment: @hanshenrik Please test this script -- https://pastebin.com/raw/DwCWH9fB . Notice where the first command is redirecting. The second command (`curl -X POST`) will have that URL.

Comment: You need openID to login. I tested from Lynx

Comment: that didn't work for me. i got the logged out HTML of hackershake's profile from curl. see here https://pastebin.com/QFVR0YXy . also, i don't see how that code could work, because you don't extract the csrf login key (called `<input type="hidden" name="fkey" value="??????????">` ) from the html when doing `curl -X GET 'https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/login'` , which you need when doing the login POST request

Comment: also, no, you don't need openID to login.. at least my php script below logs in without openID

Answer (score 3):

The url for login is not `https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/` it is `https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/login`

and the link you refer say

`curl -u username:password $URL`

not

`curl $URL -u username:password`

Try

```
USERNAME="mine@gmail.com"
PASSWORD="myPassword"

URL="https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/login"
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD $URL
```

## Update

Stack Exchange requires an additional key for login which is called `fkey`. If you inspected the login form from browser, you can see a `hidden` input field with name `fkey` and value is a hash value. It is required to identify the session and to prevent fake login attempts.

Comment: i literally said this in my post 7 days ago. >`now extract the POST URL and input elements of the form with id login-form, this includes the CSRF token, username, and password, and bunch of others`  >>>`assert ( ! empty ( $inputs ['fkey'] ), 'failed to extract the csrf token!' );`

Answer (score 3):

If you (using Chrome) look at the login form on the login page (right click, inspect, look at the html), you learn that the form is posting `email` and `password` fields to `https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/login`.

The way to do that with curl is:

```
curl https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/login -d "email=test@test.com&password=monkey"
```

If you dig through the html that is returned you can see that this is an invalid login.

The problem is that if you want to use a logged in session in a subsequent call, you'd need to store the session cookie that you're getting from the site in order to make that subsequent call.  Looking at the curl man page, you can see there's a `-c <cookie_jar_file>` option.  If you pass that in with a filename, it should save the cookies from the login call, and you should be able to make subsequent calls using the session you've estabished, and you should be in business.

EDIT:
the other answers and comments here have pointed out a couple of things missing from this answer.  It's necessary to get and subsequently post the csrf key, and the correct MIME type for the post.  It's certainly possible to do this on the command line, but would be a lot easier using a more complete language (per the accepted answer).  I did find this question that has suggestions for a tool that could potentially be used to chop out the HTML/XML snippets that would be needed to make it work: https://superuser.com/questions/528709/command-line-css-selector-tool/528728